# Counting the number of valuations via Quine algorithm in Prolog

Tags: prolog, propositional-calculus

My logic teacher said in passing that [Quines algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505466)
can be also used to count valuations. Unfortunately I
cannot get my head around how this is done in Prolog?

The program would for example give, using
the syntax from the answer in Quines algorithm:

```
?- sat_count(X+Y, C).
C = 3
```

Since the truth table for the disjunction X+Y
has 3 rows that valuate to true:

```
X   Y   X+Y
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Point of departure is Quines algorithm with its core predicate eval/2 which has the following specification. The source code of the Quine algorithm and the solution to the question can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jburse/46f7b22cab8173574d8bb9da22de0fab#file-boole-pl).

```
/**
 * eval(A, R):
 * The predicate succeeds in R with a partial evaluated
 * Boolean formula. The predicate starts with the leaves
 * and calls simp after forming new nodes.
 */
% eval(+Formula, -Formula)
```

We first experimented with a labeling predicate, that
will list all valuations without counting them. The predicate
has a fast fail feature, if the partially evaluated formula
is false (0) then labeling needs not to proceed, otherwise we
simply probe the boolean values:

```
/**
 * labeling(L, A):
 * The predicate labels the variables from the list L in the formula A.
 */
% labeling(+List, +Formula)
labeling(_, A) :- A == 0, !, fail.
labeling([X|L], A) :- value(X), eval(A, B), labeling(L, B).
labeling([], A) :- A == 1.
```

Here is an example run:

```
?- labeling([X,Y], X+Y).
X = 0,
Y = 1 ;
X = 1,
Y = 0 ;
X = 1,
Y = 1
```

From the labeling predicate we derived a counting predicate
using findall/3 from the ISO core standard. Instead of
succeeding at the end we return 1, inbetween we sum the counts.
This does the job and also profits from fast failing:

```
/**
 * count(L, A, N):
 * The predicate silently labels the variables from the list L in the
 * formula A and succeeds in N with the count of the solutions.
 */
% count(+List, +Formula, -Integer)
count(_, A, C) :- A == 0, !, C = 0.
count([X|L], A, D) :-
   findall(C, (value(X), eval(A, B), count(L, B, C)), R),
   sum(R, 0, D).
count([], A, 1) :- A == 1.
```

Here is an example run:

```
?- count([X,Y], X+Y, C).
C = 3
```

The implementation might profit from some optimizations that we didn't implement. For example assigning values to a variable that does not anymore occure in the formula could be optimized away.