# Boolean unification in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, constraints, sat

I am struggling alreay for a long time with the
following problem. I want to make the usual unification
of Prolog more smart.

Basically I want that certain variables understand that
for example 0 = ~1 and 1 = ~0. This doesn't work normally:

```
?- op(300, fy, ~).
true.

?- X = ~Y, Y = 0.
X = ~0,
Y = 0.
```

I know that that CLP(B) can do it:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.7)

:- use_module(library(clpb)).
true.

?- sat(X=:= ~Y), Y = 0.
X = 1,
Y = 0.
```

But I require something more lightweight than loading a full CLP(B) library. Any ideas?

Comment: Unification is syntactic . You are hoping to achieve a semantic interpretation whereby reasoning is done over semantic value obtained from the syntactic representation .

Comment: Yes You can and should do that but what You call `my_unification` is not unification anymore , a better name would be `my_evaluation` ,

Comment: Would it not be best if unification was reserved to mean syntactic unification ?

Comment: These is nothing wrong talking about E-unification where E is some equational theory. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#E-unification , here E = Boolean algebra/ring .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SWI-Prologs [when/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=when/2) does the job. I am using
the Quine algorithm from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505466/prolog-implementation-of-quines-algorithm-for-classical-propositional-logic-in) to partially evaluate a boolean expression.
I can then define a Boolean let/2 predicate:

```
let(X, Y) :-
   eval(Y, H),
   term_variables(H, L),
   ( L== [] -> X = H;
      cond(L, R),
      when(R, let(X, H))).

cond([X], nonvar(X)) :- !.
cond([X,Y|Z], (nonvar(X);T)) :-
   cond([Y|Z], T).
```

The above predicate will reevaluate the expression assigned
to the variable X when ever some variable inside the expression
changes. The expression is associate with the variable X through when/2. Since we see when/2 in the top-level, we see the associated expression:

```
?- let(X, ~Y).
when(nonvar(Y), let(X, ~Y))

?- let(X, Y+Z).
when((nonvar(Y); nonvar(Z)), let(X, Y+Z))
```

And we can also do our use case and even more:

```
?- let(X, ~Y), Y = 0.
X = 1,
Y = 0.

?- let(X, Y+Z), Y = 0.
Y = 0,
when(nonvar(Z), let(X, Z))

?- let(X, Y+Z), Y = 0, Z = 1.
X = 1,
Y = 0,
Z = 1
```

Comment: That is clever !